# Display some text inside a button when hover

Tags: html, css

I want to display some text inside a button but only when this one is hover using HTML or CSS.

When the button isn't hover, the main text it a title (I've already somthing working), and when you hover this with your mouse, the title slides to the top and some additionnal text appers like a description and a little "Visit >>" at the end.

I've putted my code and the thing that I need to have on a codepen page here (and at the end of this message) : https://codepen.io/floksyyt/pen/WNrVjJd

Thanks for your future help !

```css
.btn {
  opacity: 0.6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.btn span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn span:after {
  content: "\00bb";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.btn:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bienvenue chez Floksy !</h1>
    <h2>Vous vous trouvez actuellement sur la plateforme de s&eacute;lection de sous-site internet de Floksy.</h2>
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td width="5%"></td>
        <td width="25%">
          <center>Pour venir voir mon profil professionnel ainsi que mes gros projets
        </td>
        <td width="2.5%"></td>
        <td width="25%">
          <center>Si vous souhaitez d&eacute;couvrir ou en apprendre plus sur mes aventures sur Youtube et Twitch
        </td>
        <td width="2.5%"></td>
        <td width="25%">
          <center>Si vous veniez &agrave; propos de mes services d'informatique et &eacute;lectronique
        </td>
        <td width="5%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <center><button class="btn" onclick="window.location.href='somewhere';"><span>Espace Professionnel </span></button>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <center><button class="btn" onclick="window.location.href='somewhere';"><span>Espace Cr&eacute;ation Web </span></button>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <center><button class="btn" onclick="window.location.href='somewhere';"><span>Espace Services </span></button>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Example for one button :<br /><br />
      Title<br />(always visible)
      <hr>
      Description<br />(only visible by hover button)
      <hr>
      Visit >><br />(only visible by hover button)
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish your task (assuming I understand project goals).
One way to is use the 'onmouseover' and 'onmouseout' events on the button

A second way is to use JS to alter the class assignments of the hidden messages.
This is also accomplished with the same events a before except assigned to an element event listener via the 'addEventListener' function assigned to the button elements.

Here is an example of both methods.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title> Test Page </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<!-- For: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200448/display-some-text-inside-a-button-when-hover -->
<style>
 .hide { display: none; }
 #btn1Msg { background-color: pink; width: 15em; }
 #btn2Msg { background-color: lime; width: 15em; }
</style>

</head><body>
First button uses only HTML for effect<br>
<button id="btn0"
 onmouseOver="document.getElementById('demo').classList.remove('hide')"
 onmouseOut="document.getElementById('demo').classList.add('hide')"
>First Button Description</button>
<pre id='demo' class="hide">Message to be displayed on First button hover</pre>

<hr />

Second and Third buttons use JS to achieve effect

<p />
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Second Button Description">
<div id='btn1Msg' class="hide">Message to be displayed on Second button hover</div>

<p />

<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Third Button Description">
<div id='btn2Msg' class="hide">Message to be displayed on Third button hover</div>

<script>
console.clear();
const hoverShow = (IDS) => { document.getElementById(IDS+'Msg').classList.remove('hide') }; 
const hoverHide = (IDS) => { document.getElementById(IDS+'Msg').classList.add('hide') };

function init() {
  let sel = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]');
  for (let el of sel) { 
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) { hoverShow(event.currentTarget.id) }, false );
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) { hoverHide(event.currentTarget.id) }, false );
  }
} init();
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: It's mostly that I wanted, thanks for this solution.
But it is possible to display text inside the button we hover ?